# Multiple meanings of the word 'chapter'?

Tags: meaning, etymology, meaning-in-context, synonyms, ambiguity

What is the etymology and history of the word `chapter' in connection to the different things it refers to? I found after a while that chapter, [collinsDictionary](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english-thesaurus/chapter), uses it to mean not only the segment in a book/story, but also:

- convocation, council, congress, assembly, convention, synod, conclave • " The Archbishop thanked the Dean and Chapter of Westminster for inviting him to the Abbey. "
- branch, part, department, section, wing, subdivision, subsection • " the Brisbane-based chapter of Hell's Angels"

I found this to be surprising. What are some famous uses for 'chapter' outside of it referring to a book segment?

Comment: You can consider the word to mean "section of a larger body".  This works for books, Kiwanis clubs, church bodies, personal histories, etc.

Comment: Your question is unclear. If you're asking for _convincing examples_, this may well be general reference (you've turned up two fine ones yourself). And the Online Etymological Dictionary should be a first port of call. // I'm not sure that there are many / any famous speeches containing these senses of 'chapter', though.

Comment: Anything that can be organized under (or as) a **head** (Lat _caput, capitis_, whence Fr _chapter_) can be a chapter. In books, and therefore stories, it's a local division in a path metaphor; in cathedrals it's the organization of the clergy in a hierarchical metaphor; in a franchise, it's the local organization of a more widely-spread phenomenon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's French and Latin my friends. - chapter (n.) Look up chapter at Dictionary.com
c. 1200, "main division of a book," from Old French chapitre (12c.) "chapter (of a book), article (of a treaty), chapter (of a cathedral)," alteration of chapitle, from Late Latin capitulum, diminutive of caput (genitive capitis) "head" (see capitulum). Sense of "local branch" (1815) is from cathedral sense (late 15c.), which seems to trace to convocations of canons at cathedral churches, during which the rules of the order by chapter, or a chapter (capitulum) of Scripture, were read aloud to the assembled. Chapter and verse "in full and thoroughly" (1620s) is a reference to Scripture. http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=chapter